# Avoiding Duplicate entry in Full Text column

Tags: php, mysql, hash

Tables look like below  , where `chatroom name` is Full text index.

```
Chatroom name   | number of users
---------------------------------
usa             | 22
india           | 33
```

So Basically my operation will be like...I try to insert `chatroom name` if it doesnt exist , If chat room already exists just update `number of users`. how to do it ? I found that we can use some hash method that u create another unique column which contains hash of chatroom name..But I heard the there will be possible duplicate in crc32..Is there any alternative way to it ? Thanks

```
$myUnique = crc32("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think hashing needed here.
You can add one more column ID that is unique to each chat name in table.
Before insert you can fire query to check duplicate.

```
SELECT ID FROM chatroom_table WHERE chat_name="NEW_CHATROOM_NAME".
```

if it return ID you simply fire update query to update users.
else insert query to insert new chantroom name.